# Lowered reputation threshold for meta participation on some sites is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, privileges, per-site-meta

According to [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/241919), some sites have a lowered reputation (e.g. 1-rep) threshold for participating in meta:

- [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
- [Stack Overflow in Japanese / スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)

This used to work for quite a long time, until probably sometime in 2020, [when new users started reporting that they can't post on Meta Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19329/25183) (the known earliest report was on [July 24, 2020](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19142/25183)).

As a 1-rep user, trying to post something on their meta will be met with either:

- a text stating that they need 5 reputation to ask a question on meta, with a text box to input a link to their own question

  > [image]
- a text stating that they need 5 reputation to answer a question on meta

  > [image]

Why does this happen? And can we get a fix on this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: [Confirmed over on CGCC Meta that this is fixed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21989/66833)

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to reproduce this with a sock puppet account. I agree this shouldn't be happening and we should see what checks are in place and causing the inconsistent behavior. This issue has been added to our backlog and once we address it, will have the team update here. Adding [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now.

Comment: From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361140/355458) post, [status-deferred] suggests that this "[does] not line up with our Q1 roadmap that defines what we are actively working on.", however your answer seems to contradict this somewhat?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing and yet, it was done in few weeks. Weird are the ways of the deferred tag on Meta... :)